# RenderWindow.display() causes sfml to crash

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

I just started learning sfml and whenever I run the following code and try to move the window it crashes:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
using namespace sf;

int main()
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1920 , 1080), "Window", Style::Close | Style::Titlebar | Style::Resize);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
            case event.Closed:
                    window.close();
                break;
            case event.Resized:
                    std::cout << "New Window Width:" << event.size.width <<std::endl;
                    std::cout << "New Window Height:"<< event.size.height<<std::endl<<std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I remove `window.display()` from the code I can move the window without crashing it.

*I am using Codeblocks 16.01 and SFML 2.4.2*

Any ideas on why that happens?

Comment: Works fine for me that code on VS2013, so it must be something related with graphics driver or so

Answer (score 0):

Hellow, did you try to clear the window before displaying it like this:

`window.clear();`

And if it doesn't work, try to draw something before display nothing like a `sf::Sprite` for example.

Another thing that may causes that, is the size of your window. Because your not in full-screen mode so a size of `1920x1080` is too big because a external frame will be created by the os and may be it draws out the screen... but that would be really strange...

PS: prefer to use `sf::Event::Closed` for your `switch/case`

Comment: Hello, I tried drawing a blank sprite on the screen but it still crashes when i move it. Also changed the resolution to 200x200

Comment: How do you move your sprite ? I dont know how it can crashes with this code.

Comment: it's the movement of the window that crashes it not the sprite

Comment: how do you move the window then ?

Comment: I drag it with my mouse

Comment: Do you use multi threads ? If yes, your event loop must be in the same thread that created the window. If not it is really strange and could we get the whole source code then please ?

Comment: Nevermind, I reinstalled codeblocks and it worked. Thanks for the help